# Laplace transformation on an exponential

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, laplace-transform

Using the definition of Laplace transformation (and without using a table), how to find the Laplace transformation of
$$
g(t)=
\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }0\leq t\leq 4;\\
e^{3t}&\text{if }4\le t<\infty.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}f(t)dt=\int_4^\infty e^{-\lambda t} e^{3 t}dt$

$=\int_4^\infty e^{(3-\lambda) t} dt=\frac{1}{3-\lambda}\int_4^\infty e^{(3-\lambda) t} d(3-\lambda)$

$=\frac{1}{3-\lambda} \left( \left. e^{(3-\lambda)t}\right|_{t=4}^{t=\infty}\right)=\frac{1}{3-\lambda}(0-e^{(3-\lambda)4})$

for $\lambda>3$